# pgAdmin argument formats can't be mixed

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Background

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Postgresql 11.2 in Docker
- pgAdmin4 3.5

Have a column named *alias* with type `character varying[](64)`. Values have already been set on some rows before using `psycopg2`. Everything was alright then.

```
SQL = 'UPDATE public."mytable" SET alias=%s WHERE id=%s'
query = cursor.mogrify(SQL, ([values] , id))
cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

Recently, when I want to add more value using pgAdmin **GUI** as shown in the first figure, the error in the second figure happens, which says **Argument formats can't be mixed**:

[image]

[image]

Well, it turns out if insert the values using script such as **psql** or **query tool** in pgAdmin, the error does not happen, i.e., it only happens if using **GUI** of pgAdmin.

Example script:

```
UPDATE public."mytable" SET alias='{a, b}' WHERE id='myid'
```

But as the GUI is much easier to modify values, so really want to figure it out. Any idea?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the query you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Any chance you have figured out the issue here?

Comment: @LucasHendren Unluckily, not yet. Am currently using script to edit values.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I have been having the issue as well. I am looking for a solution and if I find it ill let you know. I will confirm it only appears to happen when a character varying[] is involved

Comment: Still having the issue

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug in pgAdmin 4.17.

It looks like it happens whenever you edit a `char(n)[]` or `varchar(n)[]` cell in a table (although `char[]` and `varchar[]` are unaffected).

It should be [fixed in 4.18](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/commit/f5d46bf9f1505f5570aa3e413933c105ce7b33a4#diff-6a70ae83b5f289aa834e117d2df96908).

In the meantime, you can fix it yourself without much trouble. The pgAdmin4 backend is written in Python, so there's no need to rebuild anything; you can just dive in and change the source.

Find the directory where pgAdmin4 is installed, and open `web/pgadmin/tools/sqleditor/__init__.py` in an editor. Find the line:

```
typname = '%s(%s)[]'.format(
```

...and change it to:

```
typname = '{}({})[]'.format(
```

You'll need to restart the pgAdmin4 service for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get this working with the Character Varying data type but it worked once I converted the column data type to Text.